# Replace spaces in string

Tags: python, strings, complexity

```
import re


def replace_token_regex(s, token=" "):
    return re.sub(token, '20%', s.strip())

def replace_token_inplace(s, token=" "):

    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if ord(char) == ord(token):
            s[index] = '20%'
    return s

print replace_spaces_regex("Foo Bar ")
s = list("Foo Bar ")
replace_spaces_inplace(s)
print ''.join(s)
```

The run time complexity of the above code is \$O(n)\$, can it be further optimized? or is there any better way to do the above computation?

Comment: Every character must be inspected, hence the complexity _is_ \$O(n)\$.

Comment: Do you mean `'%20'`? Do you actually want to perform URL percent-encoding, by any chance?

Comment: Its just an example. There can be anything :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid `replace`, a faster method would just split and join. This is faster simply because `.split` and `.join` are fast:

```
"20%".join(string.split(" "))
```

For a more thorough review, I'll point out that your functions aren't equivalent. The first strips whitespace and the second doesn't. One of them must be wrong!

In the second case:

```
def replace_token_inplace(s, token=" "):
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if ord(char) == ord(token):
            s[index] = '20%'
    return s
```

you are doing several non-idiomatic things. For one, you are mutating and returning a list.
It's better to just not return it if you mutate:

```
def replace_token_inplace(s, token=" "):
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if ord(char) == ord(token):
            s[index] = '20%'
```

Secondly, it'll probably be faster to do a copying transform:

```
def replace_token_inplace(s, token=" "):
    for char in s:
        if ord(char) == ord(token):
            yield '20%'
        else:
            yield char
```

which can also be written

```
def replace_token_inplace(s, token=" "):
    for char in s:
        yield '20%' if ord(char) == ord(token) else char
```

or even

```
def replace_token_inplace(s, token=" "):
    return ('20%' if ord(char) == ord(token) else char for char in s)
```

If you want to return a list, use square brackets instead of round ones.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Python standard function:

```
"Foo Bar ".replace("20%"," ")
```

It's built-in, so experts have optimised this as much as possible.

Comment: That solution seems to do the inverse of code in the question.

Comment: `"Foo Bar ".replace(" ", "20%")` should produce the correct results. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) is a link to the documentation.

Comment: I know that but I wanted to solve it without some library function just for learning purpose.